# TWS API Python_Remaining Positions

Tags: python

I am trying to get the number of filled/remaining positions using the function orderStatus() under EWrapper class.

I tried something like, print(p.orderStatus(orderId=6, filled)), which didn't work. Please help.

Thanks,

Comment: This should go to stackoverflow and you should include a minimal and complete example as per their guidelines.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with Quantitative Finance.